# How to get a specific value from a dictionary within a list

Tags: dictionary, get

I am trying to find all the keys that have the world 'symbol' and print out their respective values in one go. The data set given is wrapped in a list as well.
`[{'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'initialMargin': '2.68109529', 'maintMargin': '0.13405476', 'unrealizedProfit': '-0.07952355', 'positionInitialMargin': '2.68109529', 'openOrderInitialMargin': '0', 'leverage': '5', 'isolated': False, 'entryPrice': '0.899', 'maxNotional': '250000', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'positionAmt': '15.0', 'notional': '13.40547645', 'isolatedWallet': '0', 'updateTime': '1676641281047', 'bidNotional': '0', 'askNotional': '0'}, {'symbol': 'EOSUSDT', 'initialMargin': '3.22845093', 'maintMargin': '0.08071127', 'unrealizedProfit': '-0.06225465', 'positionInitialMargin': '3.22845093', 'openOrderInitialMargin': '0', 'leverage': '5', 'isolated': False, 'entryPrice': '1.072', 'maxNotional': '2000000', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'positionAmt': '-15.0', 'notional': '-16.14225465', 'isolatedWallet': '0', 'updateTime': '1676641497608', 'bidNotional': '0', 'askNotional': '0'}]`

So I want to pull both the 'BTCUSDT' and 'EOSUSDT' by finding the word 'symbol'

I've tried everything to get this to work.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: python, most recent edition

Comment: `[x['symbol'] for x in data if 'symbol' in x]`

Comment: I love you so much you wouldn't understand